# Outlook js plugin - Show an custom alert dialog box instead of the task pane when using my add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently developing an Office plugin for Outlook using the OnMessageSend and SmartAlerts events that will perform a few simple checks before the email is being sent.

I'm able to display custom alerts on the taskpane but i would love to be able to display them on the send button.
I can't seem to change the default alert msgbox.

On Microsoft official website i found this information regarding Smart Alerts dialog messages:

```
"The dialog's title bar. Your add-in's name is always displayed there.
The message's format. For example, you can't change the text's font size and color or insert a bulleted list.
The dialog options. For example, the Send Anyway and Don't Send options are fixed and depend on the SendMode option you select.
Event-based activation processing and progress information dialogs. For example, the text and options that appear in the timeout and long-running operation dialogs can't be changed."
```

Anyone here knows it's possible to display something like this:

[image]

Here's my even.completed example:

event.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage:  "SAMPLE TEXT TO DISPLAY"});

It's seems i can't use breaks, change colors or size.

Here's my manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>dac64749-60d7-4579-9036-cb7308b6d444</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Validator</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sample Text"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Sample Text"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000/</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.12">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <!-- Specifies the event-based activation runtime. -->
          <!-- For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch. -->
          <Runtimes>
            <!-- HTML file that references the JavaScript event handlers. This is used by Outlook on the web. -->
            <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
              <!-- JavaScript file that contains the event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
              <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
            </Runtime>
          </Runtimes>
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="CategoriesGroupMessageCompose">
                  <Label resid="CategoriesGroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MessageComposeSelectButton">
                    <Label resid="SelectButtonLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="SelectButtonLabel"/>
                      <Description resid="SelectButtonDescription"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="CategoriesGroupAppointmentOrganizer">
                  <Label resid="CategoriesGroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="AppointmentOrganizerSelectButton">
                    <Label resid="SelectButtonLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="SelectButtonLabel"/>
                      <Description resid="SelectButtonDescription"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- Enables the add-in on specified events. -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
              <LaunchEvents>
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser"/>
              </LaunchEvents>
              <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used by the add-in (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
              <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.js"/>
          <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="CategoriesGroupLabel" DefaultValue="Sample Name"/>
          <bt:String id="SelectButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Sample Name"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="SelectButtonDescription" DefaultValue="Sample Name"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can customise the error message  in Smart Alert using event.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage: message }); For more information please follow this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest

Comment: thanks for you comment, i updated my post with my manifest and my event.completed .
According to that website, the customization is extremely limited. So I'm not sure how can i achieve the customization that we want.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible with smart alerts. You need to use the `on-send` feature and use the Dialog API for displaying a rich UI for the dialogs, see [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for more information.

Read more about the on-send feature in the [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) article.

Note, you can also post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thank you so much Eugene! Will have a look into the on-send feature.