# How can I display a Custom Dialog Box using Outlook Add-in when a user clicks on the send button

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Whenever a user clicks on the send button, I want a custom dialog box to appear on the outlook screen. I have used the **Smart Alerts** to get the dialog box, but I can neither customize the popup nor collect any data from the user action on the popup. It would be helpful, if anyone could help me with creating a outlook onsend add-in using yeoman generator and Javascript!!

I tried using this:

```
</ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included event. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
            <LaunchEvents>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser"/>
            </LaunchEvents>
            <!-- Identify the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
            <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
```

This gives me a prompt, if the condition in my javascript code is satisfied but I have no control over the way my popup looks and also cannot get any data from the user action on the popup.

Comment: The answer to your question is over there [Show custom alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283614/outlook-js-plugin-show-an-custom-alert-dialog-box-instead-of-the-task-pane-whe). I know it is not marked as the accepted answer, but this is exactly what you need. I just didn't want to copy and paste the answer. Please investigate the "on-send" Outlook feature in the couple with Dialog API. All required links are inside the answer, so you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much @SlavaIvanov!! Means a lot to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook js plugin - Show an custom alert dialog box instead of the task pane when using my add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283614/outlook-js-plugin-show-an-custom-alert-dialog-box-instead-of-the-task-pane-whe)

Comment: I can't find exact code references to use "On-send" feature and Js to show a custom alert. I also want to fetch the data from my custom alert @QuackE.Duck